# How to destruct array of numbers in an object and combine to one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this object:

```
const memorized = [
 {
  verses: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  when: '2022 Jan 14'
 },
 {
  verses: [6, 7, 8, 9]
  when: '2022 Jan 15'
 },
 {
  verses: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
  when: '2022 Jan 16'
 },
...
]
```

and how can I get the total verses like this:

```
const total_verses = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 15]
```

My possible solution would be:

```
let total_verses = []
memorized.map(ar => total_verses.push(...ar.verses))
```

But I would like to do it by just filtering or mapping.

Comment: arent you doing by just mapping already

Comment: yeah, but i couldn't return `number[]` from the mapping, instead it gave me `[number[]]`, thats why i push to new array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to push when you map - that is wasting an array

EITHER push in a forEach or just flatMap the array

```js
const memorized = [ { verses: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], when: '2022 Jan 14' }, { verses: [6, 7, 8, 9], when: '2022 Jan 15' }, { verses: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], when: '2022 Jan 16'  } ];

const total_verses = memorized.flatMap(({ verses }) => verses)

console.log(total_verses);
```

Comment: thanks, i was trying `map()` but didn't get the expected result